# Calculating Maximum BLOB column value size in IBM DB2 Table

Tags: db2

I am planning to migrate IBM DB2 DB to AWS RDS using DMS tool.
There are few tables with BLOB Columns.

To ensure the BLOB columns are not truncated I want to allocate the right memory for the BLOB column during data migration.

How can I calculate the maximum value of a BLOB column stored in each of the IBM DB2 table having BLOB Column?

I am using IBM DB2 11.5.8 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LENGTHB function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-lengthb) to get the length in bytes.

So this SQL would return the max length in bytes

```
 SELECT max(lengthb(yourcolumn)) FROM yourtable
```